# AJAX auto populate dropdown base from first and second dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and has a 3 drop downs that is dynamic. My first dropdown is a services. A service has many categories and category is the second dropdown. A category belongs to a services. Now the categories has many methodologies which is the third drop down. A method belongs to category.

So here is what I have done so far.

**create.blade.php**

```
<!-- Service Id Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="service_id">Service:</label>
    <select name="service_id" class="form-control" required id="service_id">
        <option disabled selected>Choose Services</option>
            @foreach ($services as $service)
                <option value="{{ $service->id }}">{{ $service->description }}</option>
            @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<!-- Categories Id Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="category_id">Category:</label>
    <select  name="category_id" class="form-control" required id="category_id">
        <option disabled selected>Choose Category</option>
            {{-- @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach --}}
    </select>
</div>

<!-- Methodologies Id Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('methodology_id', 'Method:') !!}
     {!! Form::select('methodology_id', $methodologies, null, ['class' => 'form-control','required'])!!}
</div>
```

in my script

```
$(function() {
        $('#service_id').change(function() {

            let url = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/service/' + $(this).val() + '/categories/';

            $.get(url, function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                let select = $('form select[name= category_id]');

                select.empty();

                $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                    console.log(key + ' '+ value);
                    select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    });

    // Dynamic property dropdown for methodologies
    $(function() {
        $('select[name=category_id]').change(function() {

            let url2 = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/categories/' + $(this).val() + '/methodologies/';

            $.get(url2, function(data) {
                let select2 = $('form select[name= methodology_id]');

                select2.empty();

                $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                    console.log(key + ' '+ value);
                    select2.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

I created 2 functions in my ajax that if the first drop down change. The second drop down will be populated depends on the first drop down of the selected data. All of these is working nicely, However. I still need to select on the second dropdown before the third drop down becomes populated.

I want to populate the third drop down which is the methodologies_id depends on the first option populated by the first drop down.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your select3 is populated with respect to the selected value in select2. When your select1 is selected it populates the select2,while  there is no selected value in select2, hence the select3 won't be populated until you make a selection in select2. If you would like to populate the select3 with respect to the selection in select1, you may need to define a relation b/w the `services` and the `methodologies` and create a route for it. Or select a default value on select1 change event and trigger change event of select2 on first function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I got you question right but you want to change select 2 and select 3 to change based on the first select.

On you second function you're watching the second select for changes `$('select[name=category_id]').change(function() {` change the selector to `$('#service_id').change(function() {` and it should update if you change the first select.

You could as well refactor both functions into one.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#service_id').change(function() {

    let url = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/service/' + $(this).val() + '/categories/';

    $.get(url, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      let select = $('form select[name= category_id]');

      select.empty();

      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        console.log(key + ' ' + value);
        select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
      });
    });

    let url2 = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/categories/' + $(this).val() + '/methodologies/';

    $.get(url2, function(data) {
      let select2 = $('form select[name= methodology_id]');

      select2.empty();

      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        console.log(key + ' ' + value);
        select2.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: now it is working. But I am passing the id of the first dropdown value. I should pass the value of the second dropdown which is the category_id to get the key value of the third dropdown.

Comment: My mistake. I get the correct values. Thanks for the help! Appreciate it! Now it works! :)

Comment: Hello there @Daniel. Sorry for the incovenience but I am getting the value of the id in my first drop down that it should be the id of the first option to be populated in the second dropdown. Because a method belongs to a category. Sorry

Comment: I think this is because it is passing the `let url2 = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/categories/' + $(this).val() + '/methodologies/';` but it should be the key of the second dropdown needed to be passed in the url2.

Comment: Then you could use `let url2 = '{{ url('encoder') }}' + '/categories/' + $(category_id).val() + '/methodologies/';`  instead. `$(category_id).val()` will give you the id of the category. Sorry this was my bad then.